# Copy content of a textarea into a div and print page

Tags: jquery

I need to copy the content of a textarea into a div, and then print the page, including the new value in the div.

```
<textarea id="np01" rows="1" autofocus></textarea>
```

So, I typed some content into the textarea.

```
$("#btnPrint").click(function(){
    givemevars();
    $("#ph1").html(np01);
    window.print();    
});

function givemevars(){
    var np01 = $('#np01').val();
}
```

Problem:

1. After clicking on `#btnPrint` div `#ph1` has not only the value but also the background of related textarea (`#np01`). I need just the value, i.e. text.
2. In print preview window (`window.print()`) div `#ph1` is empty, i.e. without any new content inside.

Any help ?

Comment: `var np01` is local to `givemevars`. The click method will not have access to that variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a variable using `var` inside a function, it is local to only that function. Instead you should return the value from `givemevars()` and use that:

```
$("#btnPrint").click(function(){
    var np01 = givemevars(); //now it's local to the click callback function
    $("#ph1").html(np01);
    window.print();
});

function givemevars(){
    // this sends the value back to where this function was called (above)
    return $('#np01').val();
}
```

Another way to do this is declare the var outside of the functions and then only set/use it inside them. Generally this is a bad practice though, try to avoid using global variables when possible. For completeness here's how it'd look:

```
var np01;

$("#btnPrint").click(function(){
    givemevars(); 
    $("#ph1").html(np01);
    window.print();
});

function givemevars(){
    // note the lack of "var", this way it sets an existing variable 
    // instead of creating a new (local) one
    np01 = $('#np01').val();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change your code so your `givemevars` function returns the value of the text area, and store it in a variable to use in the click event

```
$("#btnPrint").click(function(){
    var value = givemevars();
    $("#ph1").html(value);
    window.print();

});

function givemevars(){
    return $('#np01').val();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the np01 variable scope is local to the function you need to change your code:

```
        $("#btnPrint").click(function(){
            $("#ph1").html(givemevars());
            window.print();

        });

        function givemevars(){
            return $('#np01').val();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `np01` is supposed to be an empty in the click event. Because... you don't put `return` in your original function, it means you made it `void`. So you have to use a static variable and use it in the function to store the data, which is not recommended in this case.

You can inject the html or text via `.html()` or `.text()`. It's your call.

Try and edit your code. I'm going to give you an example and working code.

```js
$("#btnPrint").click(function(){
    //givemevars();
    //$("#ph1").html(np01);
    //window.print();
    
    var content = giveMeVars();
    $('#print').text(content);
    

});

//function givemevars(){
//    var np01 = $('#np01').val();
//}


function giveMeVars() {
    return $('textarea').val();  
}
```

```css
button, textarea {
   vertical-align:top;
}

textarea {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnPrint">Print this</button>
<textarea id="np01" rows="1" autofocus></textarea>


<h3>Print result...</h3>
<div id="print"></div>
```